# Why Datagrid is not showing data?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have an application in C# + WPF and I need to fill a datagrid.

I tried to fill the DataGrid using its property ItemsSource.

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = <ElementList>;
```

Where ElementList is a List of strings.

When I run it, it generates a row for each element of the list but it does not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Does your data have [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)? [Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) will not work, also [`AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) needs to be `true` unless you created columns manually.